# redirect to original page upon ajax login

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, redirect, authentication

I am trying to implement the following scenario:

1) A user is not logged in, and on page foo.
2) The user clicks login on that page which shows a lightbox.
3) The user logs in via the lightbox.
4) The page, foo, is refreshed upon login success.

Steps 1-3 are done. In step 4 right now, the user is always redirected to their profile page upon login IF the user is logging in via that lightbox method.

I have login redirects to pages if the user is trying to GET some page which requires login access. Then the user logs in and is automatically redirected to that page the user was trying to go to. But in the above scenario, the user is already on a page, and I want to refresh that page upon login.

Any tips on how I can implement the above?

Thanks.

Comment: Assuming the lightbox form will trigger an ajax login request, on the ajax call success handler function you can add a location.reload(true) to force reloading of the current page.

Comment: @eugen already in my answer :)

Answer (score 2):

An answer to your question would be to redirect to the current page instead of "refreshing" it :

```
redirect_to request.url
```

But, be aware that this will issue a REDIRECT, which means a 302 status code (rails default). You can specify the status code you want with :

```
redirect_to request.url, :status => 301
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Make the login form in the lightbox submit via ajax (rather than the usual post). In Rails 3 just use `:remote => true` in the form. In the ajax response run some javascript that refreshes the page: `window.location.href = window.location.href;`

Note that there are many ways to accomplish your task, and this is just one option. I've found it to work well for me on my site: http://www.tmatthew.net/blog

Comment: window.location.reload() is not a good option. Suppose you try to login just after doing a POST to a page. You will 1) refresh a POST'ed page, thus sending information again 2) get a popup that tells you so 3) potentially break the user experience. A better alternative would be window.location.href = window.location.href.

Answer (score 0):

One option you can easily use in many circumstances is:

`redirect_to :back`

This just sends the browser back to the page it originated the request from. This is handy when you have a form that appears in multiple places and you want the person submitting the form to be taken back to whatever page they happened to submit it from rather than always redirecting to a certain page (like you're describing).

Comment: But if the request is an XHR, it won't actually load the page into the DOM.